# Elegant way to create a vector of reference

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

I have a vector of Foo

```
vector<Foo> inputs
```

Foo is a struct with some score inside

```
struct Foo {
    ...
    float score
    bool winner
}
```

Now I want to sort inputs by score and only assign winner to the top 3. But I don't want to change the original inputs vector. So I guess I need to create a vector of reference then sort that? Is it legal to create a vector of reference? Is there an elegant way to do so?

Comment: vector of non-owning pointers would be easier to manage

Comment: Vector of pointers is probably what you're looking for. But depending on how big your `Foo` is, it may be cheaper to simply copy. If `Foo` is really just a float and a bool, then I recommend copying the whole vector.

Comment: On a side note, sorting is so inefficient for this. You can get the top three in O(n) time by using a simple "find max" algorithm.

Comment: FWIW, it's only a few lines of code to do this in a single pass and holding a few iterators.  That will save you O(N) space and O(logN) comparisons.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. The point is to update the original inputs, not find the top 3.

Comment: If you already know who the top three are, then why are you sorting it? I'm a bit confused as to what your question is, if it's *not* about finding the top three.

Comment: You find who the top 3 are, then update them.

Comment: You can still modify the three inputs you find. No need for sorting. If that's not what you mean, then I'm sorry, but I agree with Silvio that your question is unclear.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld You could do this without another vector and in a single pass as long as you don't mind writing 16 lines of code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52047408be2ee716

Comment: Sorting a vector of integer indices seems like the easiest option to me

Comment: @SilvioMayolo no I don't know which are the top 3, and I don't know how many do I need. Let's say I need top k... sorry for not being clear

Comment: @NeilButterworth Non-owning pointers have at least 2 drawbacks: the syntactic from having to add `&` and `*` in code using them, and lack of self-documentation with no innate semantics of ownership or lack thereof. I typically prefer `std::reference_wrapper`, which clearly self-documents its purely observational semantics and gets around at least some of the syntactical problems (implicitly converting to the real referred type, although elsewhere requiring `.get()` or `for (RealType& foo: foo_refs)`). I'd recommend that or another vocabulary class, certainly for publicly exposed data at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really don't want to modify the original vector, then you'll have to sort a vector of pointers or indices into the original vector instead. To answer part of your question, no there's no way to make a vector of references and you shouldn't do so.

To find the top three (or `n`) elements, you don't even have to sort the whole vector. The STL's got you covered with [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) (or [`std::partial_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) if you care about the order of the top elements), you would do something like this:

```
void modify_top_n(std::vector<Foo> &v, int n) {
    std::vector<Foo*> tmp(v.size());
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), tmp.begin(), [](Foo &f) { return &f; });

    std::nth_element(tmp.begin(), tmp.begin() + n, tmp.end(),
        [](const Foo* f1, const Foo *f2) { return f1->score > f2->score; });
    std::for_each(tmp.begin(), tmp.begin() + n, [](Foo *f) {
        f->winner = true;
    });
}
```

Assuming the vector has at least `n` entries. I used `for_each` just because it's easier when you have an iterator range, you can use a for loop as well (or [`for_each_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each_n) as Christophe mentioned, if you have C++17).

Answer (score 4):

The only example code given was for pointers, and the IMO far more fitting `std::reference_wrapper` was only mentioned, with no indication of how it might be used in a situation like this. I want to fix that!

---

Non-owning pointers have at least 3 drawbacks:

- the visual, from having to pepper `&`, `*`, and `->` in code using them;
- the practical: if all you want is a reference to one object, now you have a thing that can be subtracted from other pointers (which may not be related), be inc/decremented (if not `const`), do stuff in overload resolution or conversion, etc. – none of which you want. I'm sure everyone is laughing at this and saying '*I'd never make such silly mistakes*', but you know in your gut that, on a long enough timeline, it *will* happen.
- and the lack of self-documentation, as they have no innate semantics of ownership or lack thereof.

---

I typically prefer `std::reference_wrapper`, which

- clearly self-documents its purely observational semantics,
- can only yield a reference to an object, thus not having any pointer-like pitfalls, and
- sidesteps many syntactical problems by implicitly converting to the real referred type, thus minimising operator noise where you can invoke conversion (pass to a function, initialise a reference, range-`for`, etc.)... albeit interfering with the modern preference for `auto` – at least until we get the proposed `operator.` or `operator auto` – and requiring the more verbose `.get()` in other cases or if you just want to avoid such inconsistencies. Still, I argue that these wrinkles are neither worse than those of pointers, nor likely to be permanent given various active proposals to prettify use of wrapper/proxy types.

I'd recommend that or another vocabulary class, especially for publicly exposed data. There are experimental proposal(s) for `observer_ptr`s and whatnot, but again, if you don't really want pointer-like behaviour, then you should be using a wrapper that models a reference... and we already have one of those.

---

So... the code in the accepted answer can be rewritten like so (now with `#include`s and my preferences for formatting):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

// ...

void
modify_top_n(std::vector<Foo>& v, int const n)
{
    std::vector< std::reference_wrapper<Foo> > tmp{ v.begin(), v.end() };

    std::nth_element( tmp.begin(), tmp.begin() + n, tmp.end(),
        [](Foo const& f1, Foo const& f2){ return f1.score > f2.score; } );

    std::for_each( tmp.begin(), tmp.begin() + n,
        [](Foo& f){ f.winner = true; } );
}
```

This makes use of the range constructor to construct a range of `reference_wrapper`s from the range of real `Foo`s, and the implicit conversion to `Foo&` in the lambda argument lists to avoid having to do `reference_wrapper.get()` (and then we have the far less messy direct member access by `.` instead of `->`).

Of course, this can be generalised: the main candidate for factoring out to a reusable helper function is the construction of a `vector< reference_wrapper<Foo> >` for arbitrary `Foo`, given only a pair of iterators-to-`Foo`. But we always have to leave something as an exercise to the reader. :P

Answer (score 3):

Here two different way of creating a `vector<Foo*>`:

```
vector<Foo*> foor; 
for (auto& x:inputs)
   foor.push_back(&x);

vector<Foo*> foob(inputs.size(),nullptr); 
transform(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), foob.begin(), [](auto&x) {return &x;});
```

You can then use standard algorithms to [sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) your vectors of pointers without changing the original vector (if this is a requirement):

```
// decreasing order according to score
sort(foob.begin(), foob.end(), [](Foo*a, Foo*b)->bool {return a->score>b->score;});
```

You may finally change the top n elements, either using [`for_each_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each_n) algorithm (if C++17)  or simply with an ordinary loop.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/W8FR6S)

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question on it's face value:

Vectors of references (as well as built-in arrays of them) are not legal in C++. Here is normative standard wording for arrays:

> There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references,
>   and no pointers to references.

And for vectors it is forbidden by the fact that vector elements must be assignable (while references are not).

To have an array or vector of indirect objects, one can either use a non-owning pointer (`std::vector<int*>`), or, if a non-pointer access syntax is desired, a wrapper - `std::reference_wrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

> So I guess I need to create a vector of reference then sort that? Is it legal to create a vector of reference?

No, it is not possible to have a vector of references. There is `std::reference_wrapper` for such purpose, or you can use a bare pointer.

Besides the two ways shown by Christophe, one more way is a transform iterator adaptor, which can be used to sort the top 3 pointers / reference wrappers into an array using `std::partial_sort_copy`.

A transform iterator simply adapts an output iterator by calling a function to transform input upon assignment. There are no iterator adaptors in the standard library though, so you need to implement one yourself, or use a library.

Comment: The iterator adapter is a great idea, I bet boost has something like that.

Comment: I thought a bit about the iterator adapter idea, and I don't think it's possible to implement, because `std::partial_sort_copy` requires random access iterators for the destination range. Forward iterators (which random access iterators also are) require their reference type to be exactly `T&` and their `operator*` to return the reference type.

Comment: @Pezo (boost) transform iterator is random access, if the wrapped iterator is random access. It *should* work I think, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: I just tried (though not with the boost adapter) and failed. One problem I encountered is that `partial_sort_copy` wants to assign a local copy of a value to the output iterator (by move), so even if we did take the address of that value it wouldn't be the address of the original value inside the input vector.